# Documentation for functions with same arity

Tags: elixir

I have two functions, with the same arity. Currently if I call `h foo/1` I only get the documentation (or function signature) of the first function. Is there a way to specify which `foo/1` I am interested in? Is there a way to add `@doc` comments to the function that will help with this? Really silly sample code below, minus any `@doc` comments.

```
def foo(bar) when is_binary(bar) do
  .
  .
  .
end

def foo(bar) when is_number(bar) do
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have one function with multiple clauses. A function is identified by a name and an arity, multiple functions cannot have the same name+arity in a module. That's why your documentation only shows for the first function clause.

There's an open issue on Elixir for warning in cases such as this: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/3707.

Comment: This is interesting. So is the proper way to document this with one `@doc` and explain each of the clauses? If so, is proper style to remove any empty lines from between the `end` and the next `def`?

Comment: Yes, single `@doc` and I usually have a single line between clauses. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can define docs alongside a default signature, like so:

```
@doc """
foo takes either a binary or an integer value and foo's it
"""
@spec foo(String.t | integer) :: result_type_here
def foo(val)

def foo(str) when is_binary(str), do: ...
def foo(num) when is_integer(num), do: ...
```

But there is no way to document each variant individually.

Comment: Actually, I have the feeling the user asked a different question as he mentioned different functions with the same arity, not same function with different arg types.

Comment: It was a typo in his code sample, he mentions "Is there a way to specify which foo/1", implying he's trying to document multiple clauses of the same function name/arity.

Comment: thats correct @bitwalker, I have fixed that now. Apologies for the confusion.